# how to use mq's many class queues

Tags: networking, linux-kernel, tc

mq has many class at default,
and it can be attached using qdisc

but mq is classless qdisc, so i cant attach filter at mq

how can i decided mq's classes decision or classify that many class.

```
tc qdisc add dev eth0 root handle 1:0 mq
tc qdisc add dev eth0 parent 1:1 handle 10:0 fq
tc qdisc add dev eth0 parent 1:2 handle 20:0 htb
```

tc qdisc show

```
qdisc noqueue 0: dev lo root refcnt 2
qdisc mq 1: dev eth0 root
qdisc fq 10: dev eth0 parent 1:1 limit 10000p flow_limit 100p buckets 1024 orphan_mask 1023 quantum 3028b initial_quantum 15140b low_rate_threshold 550Kbit refill_delay 40ms timer_slack 10us horizon 10s horizon_drop
qdisc htb 20: dev eth0 parent 1:2 r2q 10 default 0 direct_packets_stat 0 direct_qlen 1000
```

and
mq has many classes

tc class show dev eth0

```
class mq 1:1 root leaf 10:
class mq 1:2 root leaf 20:
class mq 1:3 root
class mq 1:4 root
class mq 1:5 root
...
...
...
class mq 1:40 root
```

how can i use that classes for classification
and filtering tcp packet to fq, udp packet to htb